# Waiting for a runner to pick up this job when runners are idle

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

Suddenly GitHub actions stopped working for a repo. It times out on the very first step of the action saying "Waiting for a runner to pick up this job" the requested labels are `self-hosted, windows` and we have three self-hosted Action-Runners with the labels `self-hosted, Windows` and all three show that they are idle. I tried restarting the server that the self-hosted runners are installed on, and double checked to make sure the services are still running, and everything looked fine there. The repo had a successful action run just 8 days ago, and between then and now there were no changes to the GitHub-Action yaml files.

Has anyone else run into similar issues? I'm not sure what else to try since everything looks normal, but the job isn't getting picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in the Event viewer on the server running the self hosted action runners and I found that the runners were stuck in an update loop

> Starting Actions Runner listener
> û Connected to GitHub
> Current runner version: '2.298.2'
> Generate and execute update script.
> Runner update in progress, do not shutdown runner.
> Downloading 2.299.1 runner
> Runner update process finished.
> An error occurred: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\update.finished' is denied.
> Runner listener exit with retryable error, re-launch runner in 5 seconds.

I gave the action runner user account permissions to the file `C:\Windows\system32\update.finished` and after giving it permissions the file was deleted, but that apparently allowed the update to finish and now the runners are running again as 2.299.1

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This really helped find the answer quickly - and I performed the same steps and granted security to the service account too.   Appears the runner needed updated and could not fix the problem.  Doug Lubey of Louisiana

Comment: Reference Search :  github runners "Waiting for a runner to pick up this job..." windows An error occurred: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\update.finished' is denied.